# "this" in OOP events

Tags: javascript, oop, events

Look this code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function mouseClick (container) {
        container.appendChild (document.createTextNode ("Can you show me ? Try clicking anywhere."));

        this.tryShowMe = "Yes man ! You can !"

        window.addEventListener ("click", function (event) {
            var ok = typeof this.tryShowMe === "undefined" ? "No, you can't." : this.tryShowMe;

            alert (ok);
        }, false);
    }

    window.addEventListener ("load", function () {
        new mouseClick (document.body);
    }, false);
</script>
```

The "this.tryShowMe" refers to the element "window", instead, I want to refer to the object. Can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you not use `objectName.tryShowMe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a common pitfall in JavaScript.

You're adding the event listener to `window` therefore window is calling the function, which will result in the `this` inside of the function being set to `window`.

`this` never references an outer scope in JavaScript, even if you call a plain function like `foo()` inside another function, the `this` inside of `foo` will default to the global object.

If you want to access an outer `this` you need to keep a reference to it:

```
someObject.method = function() {
    var that = this;
    function test() {
        that; // refers to someObject
        this; // refers to window
    }
    test();
}
```

For an overview on the possible values and pitfalls of `this`, take a look [here](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#how-this-works-in-javascript).